# How to store Multiple Foreign Keys in one row in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I have two tables and I would like to be able to look up all of the `employees` that are currently working with a `company`. My idea is to store an array of employees inside the `company` table:

## table initiation.

```
(
    employee_id serial not null
        constraint employees_pk
            primary key,
    name text
);

create table company
(
    company_id serial not null
        constraint company_pk
            primary key,
    name text,
    employees jsonb
        constraint company_employee_id_fk
            references employees
);
```

`[42804] ERROR: foreign key constraint "company_employee_id_fk" cannot be implemented Detail: Key columns "employees" and "employee_id" are of incompatible types: jsonb and integer.`

My desired outcome would be to have an object that looks like the following:

```
{
   "name": "A company",
   "employees": [{
      "name": "Jamie Hutber",
      "name": "John Smith",
      "name": "Frank Albert"
    }]
}
```

Comment: You need to normalize your model and split it up into many-to-many relationship table that maps employees to companies

Comment: it does not fall on the `postgresql` concept. A `foreign key` is a field(or group of fields) in a table _that uniquely identifies a row in another table_. In other words, a foreign key is defined in a table that _references to the primary key of the other table_.